# Access a web app (ASP.NET) from another machine using nginx

Tags: asp.net, nginx, remote-access

Well, here we go.
I have an instance in Azure with ubuntu and I'm trying to access an web application out of this machine (Not LocalHost).
First I've installed all dotnet things to make a test application and runned

```
dotnet new mvc
```

I check inside Azure machine localhost:5000 and this app test work well.

Then I installed nginx to access my application remotelly. When I access the public IP I can see a page of nginx.

[nginx Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDeub.png)

I've try to config thousand times to when I access the public IP the nginx redirect to my web app running in Azure Localhost.
One configuration I've try was

> /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    }
}
```

Any Idea to make this works?
Sry for bad english

Comment: Is the sites-enabled is the correct file name with config? Or it is just a directory?

Comment: Just a directory. There is a file inside this path named Default, that configuration I posted is inside this file. Thanks for try help me msgxman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed `server_name` parameter.

And if that's the only one config in config dir, then also add `default_server` [option](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) to listen directive, like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name  my.domain.com;
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    }
}
```

Change `my.domain.com` to appropriate FQDN of your Azure instance, so that you can make requests not only by entering IP address in browser, but also with a host name.

And make sure that you have included that config in nginx.conf file, like:

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

Hope it will help you to figure out.

Comment: Thanks so much mgxman. It works. I also had to enable ufw and run ufw allow 'Nginx Full'. This is for other that comming in this post :)